# Does Caffee Model work on images downloaded from google search?

Tags: neural-network, face-recognition

So, I started with this article https://towardsdatascience.com/predict-age-and-gender-using-convolutional-neural-network-and-opencv-fd90390e3ce6 for age and gender detection and, I am facing a trivial problem. I am not able to run caffe on pictures downloaded from google. Actually, it's running only on the pictures that I take from my phone or webcam. Is there any specific reason or am I doing something incorrectly? Also I wrapping all of this with flask.

```
for example:- when I feed this image that i took from google search https://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/DIYMakingaWideAngleWebcam_1478B/2010-02-16%2023-01-29.283_2.jpg


I get this as my logs:- 

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2020 11:51:57] "?[1m?[35mPOST /predicWithImage HTTP/1.1?[0m" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
  TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The 
  function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

vs Logs If I feed the picture taken from my webcam/phone.

```
Found 1 faces
printing the blob
Gender: Male
Age Range: (15, 20)

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2020 11:56:07] "?[37mPOST /predicWithImage HTTP/1.1?[0m" 200 -
```

As you can see i am getting 200 for pictures from webcam vs 500 for google pictures. It's not an issue with flask wrapper, rather I tested the code directly with a picture on my disk into cv.imread(), the Caffe model is not picking it up.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain what is happening when you're trying to run caffe on google images? in order to help you, we need to know what error you are seeing and also the code that is causing the error.

Comment: hi @Thomas, I have added the resource which was followed.